# T/SQL, Stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

Need help here. I want to get a list of Dynamic names based on the date function. Previous month, Previous month-1, Previous month -2.  Simply Getting top 10 names from Previous month, From Previous Month - 2 AND From Previous month - 3

1. Last month top ten Name. I want to get last month Dynamically  top 10 names. In this case, Last month will be March as we are in April.
2. List of Name from Current month - 2 month back   (List of Name from Feb Month)
3. From current month - 3 month (List of Name from Jan Month)

John

Thanks

Comment: TOP 10 on what basis?? **do you want it on alphabetically ??**

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume there is one table called "Table1" with name, date_created & value.

So your query could be:
(1) Previous Month

```
select * from Table1
WHERE date_created>=DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
and date_created<DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
order by Value desc
```

(2) Last two months

```
select * from Table1
WHERE date_created>=DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-2, 0)
and date_created<DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
order by Value desc
```

(3) Last 3 months

```
select * from Table1
WHERE date_created>=DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-3, 0)
and date_created<DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
order by Value desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Datediff(Month,Date,GETDATE()) Mon
    ,ROW_NUMBER()Over (partition by Datediff(Month,date,GETDATE()) ORDER BY date) RNO ,* 
    FROM Table
)A 
WHERE mon <=3 and mon > 0 and rno<=10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **tally** table then use this to get the names of the previous 10 months:

```
SELECT TOP 10 n AS A, DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, 0 - n, GETDATE())) FROM tally;
```

To create a **tally** table see [SQL ServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/)